# Getting specific value from an array with PHP

Tags: php

If I have an array in the following format:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [c] => 1 [q] => value 1. ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [c] => 1 [q] => value 2...
```

and I need to get

> value 1

Shouldn't I be able to get it by doing something like?

```
$myArray[0]['q']
```

FOr some reason I'm not getting anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element is inside an `object`, you need to do,

```
  echo $myArray[0]->q;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$myArray[0]->q` it is an object not an array.